# How can I "move" Windows Media Player from my Windows 7 laptop to my Windows 8.1 laptop?

Tags: windows-media-player

I have a work computer that I'll have until the middle of Decemcer 2016. It runs Windows 7 Enterprise. It has Windows Media Player installed on it, which can properly play back DVDs I have made with a DVD recorder hooked up to my TV.

On my Windows 8.1 computer, Windows Media Player cannot play DVDs. VLC doesn't happen to play the DVD properly; it cannot find the DVD menu, and the closed captioning only shows 20% of the time.

I want to know if there is a way to "move" the Windows Media Player files from the Windows 7 computer, onto my Windows 8.1 computer, so that I can run the DVD-playing WMP on my Windows 8.1 computer?

Comment: It doesn't work that way. You're not going to be able to.

Comment: can people help me understand why this post is downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be near impossible to do this (probably impossible). You can't just move or copy programs to another computer (especially since it's almost apart of Windows). It has registry keys, dependencies, and files spread throughout the filesystem. The exe file you use to start up Windows Media Player merely loads the files it's instructed to, and launches them. What you see on-screen is just what they create as a whole.

Comment: I suspected it would be really difficult, but I didn't know it was actually probably impossible. I had thought some really smart people out there would be able to do it!

Answer (score 1):

I'll cite:

> Microsoft decided not to pay for DVD decoding software in Windows 8.x, so Windows Media Player won't play them. You need to download and install a program like VLC Media Player, an open-source, free player that will play just about anything you ever come across.

from [here](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2229969/windows-play-dvds.html)

Maybe you are using a very old or release version of VLC, but VLC should properly play your DVD, maybe you're doing it wrong. Go to their official site and download the latest version: [VideoLAN VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html)